# Setting a Bitmap Imageview from Custom ListAdapter and ListView in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, popup, android-alertdialog

I have a Fragment in which listview having a button calling a alertdialog with some info to fill , on such is imageView which needs to be set with Camera Captured image how do i do it

Steps taken

in ListViewAdapter class

```
 private void camerafirstOnClickEventHandler(int num) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUriLandAdapter = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUriLandAdapter);
        if (num == 2) {
            ((Activity) con).startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQ2);
        }

    }



    public  void previewCapturedImage(ImageView imageView, Uri uri) {
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath(),
                    options);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            arrBitmaps.add(bitmap);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In Fragment Class

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
landAdapter.previewCapturedImage(landAdapter.uprootImage,landAdapter.fileUriLandAdapter);


}
```

but the PreviewCapturedImage is not getting called

Comment: It has possible to done with `listeners`

Comment: can you paste the code i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an interface

```
    public interface onGetImage{
   void onItemClicked();    
    }
```

Implement the interface on your Fragment Class and set the listener using your adapter object.
FragmentClass:

```
@Override
public void onItemClicked(){
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUriLandAdapter = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUriLandAdapter);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQ2);
}
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
landAdapter.previewCapturedImage(landAdapter.uprootImage,landAdapter.fileUriLandAdapter);


}
```

ListViewAdapter:

```
onGetImage callback;
public void setListener(onGetImage callback){
this.callback=callback;
}

private void camerafirstOnClickEventHandler(int num) {

        if (num == 2) {
            callback.onItemClicked();
        }

    }
```